# jquery validation max property reads only first digit?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with input like:

```
<input name="students" id="students" type="number" max=13 required >
```

I do nothing special in the booting, just:

```
$('#mainForm').validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {            
        // doing things
    }
});
```

- Entering 2 triggers the "Please enter a value less than or equal to 13."-message.
- Entering 111 however is ok. So it is only validating the first character, as an integer?!
- 14 is not ok! Now, it is checking also the second character!

Also tried

```
max="13"
```

with same results. I assume I miss something basic?

UPDATE JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/630/

Comment: i think your validation working fine

Comment: Can you please link it on jsfiddle, or anywhere else, where the validation library you're using is linked in as well?

Comment: Yes, can you either put it in a snippet here or link to a fiddle, I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: I am trying to isolate it to put in fiddle. I assume I have broken code somewhere in my huge form since you all like the syntax. I have no console errors though.

Comment: jsfiddle added in question

Comment: You want bootstrap validation  or jquery validation.js ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating from 1.11.0 to 1.11.1 solved my issue!

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```